# Set PYMYSQL connection using user given values (host,user,password,db) from ui

Tags: database, pymysql

I am trying to do this:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",
                                 user="root",
                                 password="",
                                 db='mydb',
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

and it works just fine, connection works. But what i want to know is that, is there a way to set values for host,user,password,db like:

user enters value in a UI dialog and those values are set to these 4 elements.(Tell me if it doesn't make sense)

I have created a UI dialog that has 4 QlineEdits to take values for host, user, password and db.

[This is the UI dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNCCh.jpg)

So can someone tell me if this can be done or not? If so, how?

Comment: Have you searched for any sample code or tutorials?

Comment: @ergohack i have tried to find tutorials and sample codes, but in all of them, db connection was made by setting values like above. host="localhost" like this.